# As a absolutely-positioned child of a flex container does not participate in flex layout, how to center an element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

How to center an element of a child of a flex container absolutely-positioned?

The container is already set to `justify-content:center`, but since the child is absolutely positioned, that doesn't affect it and it doesn't center.

The logo (issue at hand is with the logo) is being 'absolutely positioned' as to be able to apply z-index, so I can have it clickable (before it would get lost among the several layers and I wouldn't see it or be able to click it).

I'm attaching images to explain my point (please bear with me as I can't embed images - not enough stackoverflow karma for that). Relevant code below.

- [Situation now, the logo doesn't center above the navigation menu, on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ1FL.png)
- [All ok on desktop, given on large screens I'm forcing a `float: left` to implement the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uDMF.png)
- [The intended result (I've manipulated the screenshot to show the intended final result). How to achieve this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yQdF.png)

This is what I've tried:

- Played with flex box centering until I realized that wouldn't work for absolutely positioned child elements
- Used, `display: block`; `margin-left: auto`; `margin-right: auto`; but this didn't make any difference

How do I get to center the logo above the navigation bar on the mobile view? And be easy on me, I'm a beginner :-)

> Relevant HTML:

```
<header class="masthead__navigation mb-auto d-flex w-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
      <div class="inner">
        <a class="inner-masthead" href="#"><img src="assets/images/logo.jpg" style="max-height:40px; width:auto;"></a>
        <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Join Newsletter</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

> Relevant CSS:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {

    .masthead__navigation {
                padding-right: 2.5rem !important;
                padding-left: 4rem !important
    }

    .nav-masthead .nav-link {
                color: #262626 !important;
              color: rgba(26, 26, 26, .5) !important;
    }

    .nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
    .nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
            border-bottom-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, .5) !important;
    }

    .nav-masthead .active {
              color: #000 !important;
              border-bottom-color: #000 !important;
    }
}

.masthead__navigation {
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
        padding-bottom: 0 !important;
        width: 100vw !important;
        position: absolute !important
}

.inner-masthead {
    margin-bottom: 0;
        position: absolute !important;
        display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
        z-index: 4 !important
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
          padding: .25rem 0;
          font-weight: 700;
            color: #999;
          color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
          background-color: transparent;
          border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
            z-index: 4 !important
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
          border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
          margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
          color: #fff;
          border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
    .inner-masthead {
        float: left;
    }
    .nav-masthead {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use media query and for logo `inner-masthead` change `position:relative` and `text-align: center` on mobile. Or even not need media query, I just tried on your web page, cust change from absolute, to relative, and add text-align center, it will work :D

Comment: Super thanks @Goku, applied `position:relative`, and that helped but `text-align: center` didn't, I then brought flex child centering to the child CSS with `display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; ` And that worked

Comment: you know what you have to do now ^^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For a positioned box (that is, one with any position other than static), the z-index property specifies:
>   1)The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
>   2)Whether the box establishes a local stacking context.

According to [MDN - z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index), the z-index works on every element with a position other than static. Maybe you should give it a try with `position:relative` or similiar, which won't shoot the element out of its parent.

Comment: Thanks @d-shaller, with `position:relative` and  `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center` for the child CSS it worked.